# Click outside not working for mat-select in Chrome Version 80 when Angular application is upgraded from v9 to v14

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, angular-material

We recently upgraded our angular application from v9 to v14. However all the drop downs in our application did not close when we clicked outside the drop down. This is specifically happening for Chrome version 80. Below is example of how drop downs are implemented in the application

```
 <div id="status" class="disp-flex">
            <div class="status-selector">
                <mat-label class="header-labels">STATUS</mat-label>
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="white-bg">
                    <form [formGroup]="statusSelectionForm">
                        <mat-select id="vehicle-status-selector" placeholder="Select" floatlLabel="never" formControlName="statusForm" multiple (openedChange)="statusSelectorToggled($event)" disableOptionCentering panelClass="panelClass">
                            <mat-select-trigger>Select</mat-select-trigger>
                            <mat-option #allStatusSelected (click)="toggleAllSelection()" [value]="'0'">All</mat-option>
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let status of statusFilterList" [value]="status.name" (click)="togglePerOne()">
                                {{getLoanerStatusDisplayString(status.name)}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </form>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Tried some articles where changes in polyfills.ts was suggested but couldn't make out much of it.
Any approaches is appreciated.